# Django chain multiple queries in view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have three models:

- Course
- Assignment
- Term

A `course` has a ManyToManyField which accesses Django's default User in a field called `student`, and a ForeignKey with `term`

An `assignment` has a ForeignKey with `course`

Here's the related models:

```
class Assignment(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    date_due = models.DateField(blank=True)
    time_due = models.TimeField(blank=True)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)

class Course(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    section = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    professor = models.ForeignKey("auth.User", limit_choices_to={'groups__name': "Faculty"}, related_name="faculty_profile")
    term = models.ForeignKey(Term)
    students = models.ManyToManyField("auth.User", limit_choices_to={'groups__name': "Student"}, related_name="student_profile")
```

When a user logs in to the page, I would like to show them something like this [bootstrap collapse card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwkBL.png) where I can display each term and the corresponding classes with which the student is enrolled.

I am able to access all of the courses in which the student is enrolled, I'm just having difficulty with figuring out the query to select the terms. I've tried using 'select_related' with no luck although I may be using it incorrectly. So far I've got `course_list = Course.objects.filter(students = request.user).select_related('term')`. Is there a way to acquire all of the terms and their corresponding courses so that I can display them in the way I'd like? If not, should I be modeling my database in a different way?

Comment: Please provide your relevant models/fields from your models.py file.

Comment: @sytech The question has been updated

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values

You could use `values` or `values_list` here to get the fields of the related model `Term`.

For example expanding on your current request:

To retrieve all the `Term`s' `name` and `duration` for the `Course`s in your queryset

`Course.objects.filter(students = request.user).values('term__name', 'term__duration')`

I am not sure what the fields are of your `Term` model, but you would replace `name` or `duration` with whichever you are trying to get at.

Answer (score 0):

I think it helps you

```
terms = Terms.objects.filter(....) # terms
cources0 = terms[0].course_set.all() # courses for terms[0]

cources0 = terms[0].course_set.filter(students=request.user) # courses for terms[0] for user
```